# Excel vba odbc connection Oracle failed Automation error

Tags: excel, oracle11g, odbc, vba

I wnat to use the Excel VBA to connect Oracle database by odbc,
but it doesn't work,I have setting the ODBC datasource in the system datasource name before, and the Test Connection is work!

[image]

VBA Code:

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.connection
    Dim connString
    connString = "DSN=HR;Uid=HR;Pwd=HR"
    Dim rsRecords As New ADODB.Recordset

    conn.Open connString
    rsRecords.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rsRecords.Open "select * from GOLDLOT", conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

    If conn.State = adStateOpen Then
      MsgBox rsRecords.recordCount
    Else
       MsgBox "no connection"
    End If

    rsRecords.Close
    Set rsRecords = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

When execute the code result is

> Run-time Error '-2147467259 (80040e37)'
>   Automation error

like this image

[image]

I'm first time to use the VBA,Please help me.
thx.